# How to use onClick function inside innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, innerhtml

This is my JS file, it is one of reusable HTML components since I'm not using any framework. Before this I'm using ReactJS, since for some reason, I required not to use any framework for frontend.

My question is I want to make onClick function for the button. I thought it is the same thing as using JSX in ReactJS but it doesn't work. I want to add the `<script>` tag in the `innerHTML` but I don't think it is relevant because this is already a javascript file.

```
class Header extends HTMLElement {
    connectedCallback() {
        this.innerHTML =
           `
             <button onclick="">Try it</button>
           `
    }
}

customElements.define('main-header', Header);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<button onclick="fn()">Try it</button>`
Or you can write code in the quotes directly:
`onclick="console.log('click')"`

Answer (score 1):

HolaPz is correct, but to more clearly demonstrate-

```js
function buttonClicked()
{
  console.log("You son of a gun, you did it");
}

class Header extends HTMLElement {
    connectedCallback() {
        this.innerHTML =
           `
             <button onclick="buttonClicked()">Try it</button>
           `
    }
}

customElements.define('main-header', Header);
```

NOTE: when buttonClicked is called, the "this" context will be set to the Window object and only top-level functions will be available. Depending on how you want to code going forward, it might make sense to use this.querySelector inside connected callback to get a reference to the button and then manually add a bound function or event listener (via addEventListener) to it.